# Visual Studio 2012 - Wpf Designer Performance

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2012

For test purposes, I'm creating a WPF form with 2000 elements:

```
<TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,19,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="241"   Text="Static Text" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="48" FontWeight="Bold" TextAlignment="Center"/>
```

All the 2000 elements are inside a StackPanel with Orientation property set to Vertical.

Now, when I drag or resize a textbox (in the designer) the WPF Designer freezes and hangs.
Is there a way to optimize design performances?

Thank you.

Comment: Are all those elements are in the same control object?

Comment: The .xaml file is something like:
    <StackPanel>
      <TextBox..../>
      ..... *2000
    </StackPanel>

Comment: You should really be using an `ItemsControl` instead of creating this monstrosity.

Comment: @HighCore Maybe monstrosity is in your understanding...I said "for test purposes"; it means that I really need 2000 WPF textboxes to edit them in the designer.

Comment: @Riccardo no you don't. No real, serious, usable UI in the world has 2000 TextBoxes in a single screen. You can't really expect your end user to have to deal with that. And no, people don't use the Visual Studio designer in WPF except maybe to see some quick preview. They type XAML manually, which produces much better results.

Comment: @Riccardo you should really post more details about what you need to do, so that we can tell you the proper way to do it in WPF, instead of just throwing code at the wind and expecting it to somehow work.

Comment: @HighCore maybe you need to read the whole question before posting any kind of response. I'm not creating an Usable UI (and this is quite obvious). I'm  testing some functionalities and asking something to expert people about WPF Designer Performances. Do you know something about WPF designer performances? If you don't have a reply you don't need to respond just for spend your time in some alternative way. Your time is precious; spend it in a better way. 
Anyway, thank you and have a good day.

Comment: @Riccardo my point is `what do you want the designer for?` it is completely irrelevant. You don't need it. Period. You can create extremely complex WPF UIs in pure XAML without resorting to any sort of designer. Your time is also precious, don't waste it trying to get anything useful from a broken Visual Studio designer.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to increase performance is by splitting up your code into controls. The designer is slow, and most of the times I end up using the built-in Visual Studio XML editor.

Comment: Or creating them dynamically, which has its downfalls.

Comment: I need to use the editor to draw HMI Pages. I can't create the component dynamically

Comment: I guess designer does some O(n^2) compare/calculation operations between n elements which are bound to same control. Such as computing overlapped pixel blending . 2000 textboxes are too many. Maybe a collection can help. Which looks like a matrix.